# Fill a gridview or matrix and a button saves it in the database c# SAP Business One SDK

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, sapb1

I use Visual Studio with SAP Business One SDK.

In this example I used a GridView and a simple select on the `POR1` table but what I would like to do is that when I fill in a GridView or a matrix what I write registers in the database so in the table `por1`, I made the example on both fields in the red frame (Photo Attachment).

Please, what do I do so that what I write here is stored in the database in the table `por1` and in the fields `U_QtyEnCours` and `U_StatutMarch`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this.

The first is using a direct SQL write - this is the fastest and is allowed for UDFs, but may be frowned upon depending on who your SAP Partner is. You also won't get any History logging.

You can use the SAP-DI `Documents` object to iterate over the `Purchase Orders`, and update the lines one by one - this is logged, but can be slow.

You could also just export it to a file and update it using the Data Transfer Workbench (DTW) which is logged, and also has all the error handling built in.